# How to switch to my local branch

Tags: git

I am new in GIT and was told to deliver a fix after rebasing from master. I did the same and resolved a few merged conflicts. Now I see the below status of my branch:

```
$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at 14ed27c7)
  develop
  feature/myferaturestream
```

Where myferaturestream is the GIT branch having all my fixes - I am not sure how to navigate to that branch now as I get the below error

```
$ git branch feature/myferaturestream
fatal: A branch named 'feature/myferaturestream' already exists.
```

Comment: use git checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still haven't completed the rebase yet, that's why the head is currently in detached state. Just to be safe, you should abort the rebase, and do it again.

```
git rebase --abort
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
# resolved the conflicts
git add *resolved_file_name*
git rebase --continue
```

Note: In case of merge instead of rebase, just adding the files and committing would have sufficed.

Answer (score 1):

`git branch` is for creating branches.

To switch branches, you need `git checkout`:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `git checkout <branch-name>`

`git branch <branch-name>` will create new branch

while `git checkout <branch-name>` will switch you to that branch

Answer (score 0):

if you have uncommitted changes and you still dont want to commit them, you can stash them by `git stash` before changing your local branch

and changing local branch is, as other guys say: `git checkout other_branch_name`

to create new branch from other branch:

`git checkout -b new_branch_name`